# Why singlet and triplet states are not mentioned when dealing with inorganic semiconductors or other heavy materials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, fluorescence

Singlet and triplet states get attention in organic materials (fluorescence, phosphorescence, upconversion). Why singlet/triplet states are never mentioned in the context of inorganic semiconductors, rare-earth materials etc.?

[image]([source](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/photchem.htm))